# How to create a TextField on a Card

Tags: flutter

How can i create a TextField on a Card.
In a Function i return a Card. Here i needed to implement a TextField.
This is my Code:

```
return new Card(
        color: Colors.white70,
        child: new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Expanded(child: new Text("Bemerkung", style: style,)),
                  new TextField(

                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
```

everytime i wanted to debug, this Exception was thrown:

```
I/flutter (17588): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (17588): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (17588): BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
I/flutter (17588): These invalid constraints were provided to RenderRepaintBoundary's layout() function by the
I/flutter (17588): following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
I/flutter (17588):   _RenderDecoration._layout.layoutLineBox (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:747:11)
I/flutter (17588): The offending constraints were:
I/flutter (17588):   BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
```

i dont know why it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap TextField with Expanded widget,

```
new Card(
        color: Colors.white70,
        child: new Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Expanded(child: new Text("Bemerkung",)),
                  new Expanded(
                    child: new TextField(

                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
```